# Laravel validation 'required' when file is chosen

Tags: laravel

I have a form for files uploading and there are 2 input fields for each file ([upload] and [expiration_date])

I don't know how to use the laravel required_if validation rule because of this array brackets. So for example if a file is chosen the expiration date should be filled and if there is no file then expiration date doesn't matter.

i have this rules now:

```
$rules = [
    'upload.*' => 'file|max:5120|mimes:pdf,jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
    'expiration_date.*' => 'required_if:upload:??????????'
];


<input type="file" name="upload[]"/><label for="expiration_date">G&uuml;ltig bis: *</label>
                                    <input name="expiration_date[]" type="text">
```

How to validate expiration_date if file is chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `required_with` rule, not `required_if`.

```
$rules = [
    'upload.*' => 'file|max:5120|mimes:pdf,jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
    'expiration_date.*' => 'required_with:upload.*|date'
];
```

I also added the `date` rule as it's a date.